# How to define font sizes in bootstrap sass port?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

i'm new to twitter bootstrap sass port and have a few questions about font size definitions.

in _variables.scss is defined:

```
$font-size-base:          14px !default;
[...]
$font-size-h1:            floor(($font-size-base * 2.6)) !default; // ~36px
$font-size-h2:            floor(($font-size-base * 2.15)) !default; // ~30px
$font-size-h3:            ceil(($font-size-base * 1.7)) !default; // ~24px
$font-size-h4:            ceil(($font-size-base * 1.25)) !default; // ~18px
```

I want to change the base font-size to 16px. Do that mean that i have to change the multiplier (2.6) to an other value if i want to keep the font-size of ~36px for my h1? And from where are these different defined multipliers come from or with other words why using multipliers (2.6, 2.15, 1.7 etc). Is this best practise?

the next unclear definition for me is:

```
//** Unit-less `line-height` for use in components like buttons.
$line-height-base:        1.428571429 !default; // 20/14
```

20/14? I think 14 is the base font-size. But for what is 20 standing?

Sorry for my bad english und thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you change `$font-size-base` to 16 then `$font-size-h1` will now be 41.6 (or 41 since `floor` is used). From the comments it seems like the goal is to increase the size by an equal amount for each variable (6px). For `$line-height-base`, 20/14 is 1.428571429 expressed as a fraction.

Comment: The comment 20/14 means that $line-height-base of 1.428571429 (at the default $font-size-base of 14px) would result in values of line-height 20px and font-size 14px, which in [font declaration shorthand](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/font-shorthand/) would be `font: <font-style> <font-variant> <font-weight> **20px/14px** <font-family>;`.